# Three.LinePieces with different materials (colors)?

Tags: javascript, graph, three.js, visualization

I was trying to draw a dense graph with more than 10k edges using three.js.

LinePieces was used for better performance but I could not figure out how to specify different colors for each edge (Line) since only one "material" could be used to create the Line object.

Here's some of the code:

```
function drawEdges() {
    edgeGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    edgeMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ opacity: 0.1 });
        foreach source-target node pair:
            edgeGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(source.x, source.y));
            edgeGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(target.x, target.y));
    }
    var edges = new THREE.Line(edgeGeometry, edgeMaterial, THREE.LinePieces);
    scene.add(edges);
}
```

My question is: Is it possible to use different materials if using THREE.LinePieces? Any hint is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `WebGLRenderer`, you can.

In your geometry, you need to specify `geometry.colors`, an array of `THREE.Color()`, whose length is equal to the number of vertices.

Then you specify your material and mesh like so:

```
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {
    color: 0xffffff,
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
} );

var mesh = new THREE.Line( geometry, material, THREE.LinePieces );
```

Example: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_lines_colors.html

three.js r.57

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @WestLangley. I was using CanvasRenderer as it provides better line rendering result. I guess it is better for me to switch to WebGLRenderer.